# Laravel 5 Twilio Namepace

Tags: laravel, twilio, laravel-5

I am implementing Twilio in Laravel 5, the tutorial I am using is very good https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/09/getting-started-with-twilio-and-the-laravel-framework-for-php.html.

Do you know what the namespace is for laravel 5?
I am getting
Class 'Services_Twilio_Twiml' not found

Thanks

Comment: I use Twilio in some of my applications and found using the aloha package very handy. https://github.com/aloha/laravel-twilio

Answer (score 3):

If you install the [twilio/sdk](https://packagist.org/packages/twilio/sdk) package via composer you should have access to all the Twilio classes automatically, since laravel uses composer's autoloading.

They are not really namespaced. You would use `\Services_Twilio_Twiml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell composer to load your Twilio folder by adding :

```
"autoload" : {
   "classmap" : [ "your/Twilio/folder" ]
}
```

to your composer.json

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you clearly you have put your Twilio code in a given file and you are getting this error saying "Class 'Services_Twilio_Twiml' not found".
I am writing here possible reason you are getting this.

1. /config/services.php- you have not added Twilio details which are 
   i. sid
   ii. token
   iii. from
2. in file in which you have integrated your Twilio code, you have to ensure to write use Twilio;
3. In your app.php you have to add in providers section Twilio which you are using for example: 'Aloha\Twilio\TwilioServiceProvider'
   and aliases section 'Twilio'    => 'Aloha\Twilio\Facades\Twilio',.
   If you look at this you might find answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5 (and older Laravel 4 applications) I suggest using the [aloha/twilio](https://github.com/aloha/laravel-twilio) package. It provides some code samples in the readme file that should help you get going quickly. One can inject a configured object using the TwilioInterface type hint which has methods to send SMSs MMs and calls.